# Access Table data from from elisp using headline ID

Tags: org-mode

I have a bunch of recipes under different headline, and each have an ingredient list specified as a table.

I would like to access that table as an list in a src block using the headline id, same as if I where to use the name table name (which is very easy)

Truth to be told I have a usecase where I'd like to do the same for lists.

```
* Recepies
** Killer Sandwich
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID: 0123
   :END:
   A really good sandwich!
   #+name: sandwich_recipie
   | 1   | piece | bread |
   | 100 | g     | cheese |
   | 100 | g     | butter |

#+begin_src elisp :var data=sandwich_recipie headline_id=0123 :results output
(= sandwich_data (magic-org-function-to-get-first-table-as-list headline_id))
#+end_src
```

So far I've been looking into org-element, but it seems like I'm not smart enough to use that... sorry

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have figured out almost everything. Using `:var data=heading` and `#+name: heading` already does the conversion of a table into a list for you and binds it to a variable by that name. Here's a full example:

```
* Recipes
** Killer Sandwich
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID: 0123
   :END:
   A really good sandwich!
   #+name: sandwich_recipe
   | 1   | piece | bread |
   | 100 | g     | cheese |
   | 100 | g     | butter |

#+begin_src elisp :var data=sandwich_recipe headline-id="0123" :results output
(require 'seq)
(princ (format "Recipe: %s\n" headline-id))
(dolist (line data)
  (seq-let (amount unit ingredient) line
    (princ (format "%s%s of %s\n"
                   (if (= amount 1) "one " amount)
                   unit
                   ingredient))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Recipe: 0123
: one piece of bread
: 100g of cheese
: 100g of butter
```

Here's a simpler source block that shows just the conversions:

```
#+begin_src elisp :var data=sandwich_recipe :results value drawer
data
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results: 
((1 piece bread) (100 g cheese) (100 g butter))
:end:
```